# ox.graph_from_bbox() function of OSMNX library in python gives incomplete graph

Tags: python, networkx, scatter-plot, osmnx

I have a piece of code which provides the route from a source point to destination point.
In the below code, origin_lat and origin_long are the source coordinates and dest_lat and dest_long are the destination coordinates

```
G = ox.graph_from_bbox(origin_lat,dest_lat,origin_long,dest_long, network_type='drive')
origin_point = (origin_lat, origin_long) 
destination_point = (dest_lat, dest_long)
origin_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G, origin_point,method='euclidean')
destination_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G, destination_point,method='euclidean')
route = nx.shortest_path(G, origin_node, destination_node, weight='travel_time')
```

But for some coordinates, I am not getting a complete route from source to destination. I have attached the screenshot of the output where I have plotted the route on ScatterMapbox [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VoRp.png)
The black route is not reaching the source and destination, means the graph itself is incomplete. Can anyone help me out with this.

Comment: is it the case that the nearest nodes are further away from your points in this case?  i.e. expected, shortest path is between two nodes, not two points

Comment: yes exactly, the nearest nodes are far away from the source and destination

Comment: so it's not an incomplete graph.  Just the fact no nodes have been contributed to OSM near points you are interested in

Comment: So what can be done to achieve the same?

Comment: You can enlarge your bounding box to download a larger graph.

Comment: I am taking the source and destination from user and giving their coordinates to the graph_from_bbox function. How could I enlarge the bounding box can you plz suggest. Thanks for replying sir!